# How to get hold of fields of object under test using spring and mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have a spring service class where I am submitting few tasks to Executor under @PostConstruct method. I have written few tests but their behavior is not same in all runs. Some times all pass, sometime few fails though condition is satisfied.

```
Class A {

   Private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

   private final Object obj1
   private final Object obj2;

  @Autowired
  public A(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
  this.obj1 = obj1;
  this.obj2 = obj2;
 }

 @PostConstruct
 public void process() {
   executorService.submit(() -> {
    obj1.doSomething();
    obj2.doOtherthing();
  });

 }

//Some other methods.....

}


Class ATest {

   A a;

   @Mock
   Object obj1;

   @Mock
   Object obj2;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      a = new A(Obj1, Obj2);
   }

  @Test 
  public void processTest {

      doNothing.when(obj1.doSomething);
      doNothing.when(obj1.doOtherthing);
      a.process();
      verify(obj1).doSomething();
      verify(obj2).doOtherthing();

 }

 @Test
 public void otherTest {

   //some test

 }

 }
```

So I want to have access of executorService in test class so that I can monitor what is happening why tests are behaving differently.

Any suggestion or recommendation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a package private method for your `executorService`, and use it in test to get `executorService`, however your test class and class under test should be in the same package.

```
ExecutorService getExecutorService() {
   return executorService;
}
```

Besides this you could make use of `@InjectMocks` annotation instead `@Before setUp()`.

```
@InjectMocks
private A a;
```